# Use one function for 2 properties in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 different properties :

```
$scope.totalPendingDisplayed = 15;
$scope.totalResolvedDisplayed = 15;
```

Each of this properties is binded to different containers with `ng-repeat` (this properties is used for `limitTo` )

When I click on button "Load More" (`ng-click="loadMore(totalResolvedDisplayed)"`) I want to execute function `loadMore`

```
$scope.loadMore = function(totalDisplayed) {
            totalDisplayed += 15;
        };
```

But this function doesn't change input field, which is one of `totalPendingDisplayed  or totalResolvedDisplayed`.

I don't want to write 2 similar function for each property. How can I solve this?

Comment: I don't get you! What do you mean by `input field`?

Comment: `input field` - I pass `totalPendingDisplayed ` or `totalResolvedDisplayed ` to my `loadMore` function as input parameter

Comment: I guess you are only getting the value of your svope variable in the loadmore function. To get a reference you need to either use a object or change your function to access the rigjt scope veriable directly based on a flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send it as a string:

```
ng-click="loadMore('totalResolvedDisplayed')"
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.loadMore = function(totalDisplayed) {
            $scope[totalDisplayed] += 15;
        };
```

Comment: seems like solution. Thanks